# saving array to txt file

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, string, file-io

I've got an array (@bigtable), filled with strings, and I want to save them to file where every row from array will be separate line, here is my code for saving file:

```
  def savefile
    @bigtable = Rails.cache.read("pass")
    doc = "wyniki.csv"
    File.open(doc, "w", :type => 'text/html; charset=utf-8'){ |f| f << @bigtable}
    send_file(doc, :disposition => 'attachment')
  end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: By the way, unless you're using @bigtable elsewhere, you should use a locale variable instead of an instance one (bigtable instead of @bigtable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the actual question? Writing the array?

```
f << @bigtable.join("\n")
```

*(If it's actually big, and you're having memory issues, write it line-by-line.)*

If it's a CSV file, why set the type to `"text/html"`? Would `"text/csv"` be more appropriate?

Comment: I'm so silly. I was doing it in loops and I was adding `\n` using single quotes - that was the problem - but thanks! Your solution is shorter ;)

Comment: @ofcapl No problem. Although using single-quotes shouldn't have been an issue; it would work either way.

Comment: but it doesn't - everything was written in a single line, and `\n` was there as a text

Comment: @ofcapl Oh, duh; single-quotes don't do the escape chars--sorry.

Comment: Odd downvote for a correct answer that the OP verified the correctness of.

Answer (score 2):

```
...
File.open("wyniki.csv", "w") do |f|
  @bigtable.each do |row| f << row end
end
...
```

Comment: it was mine solution which I mentioned in Dave's answer comments ;)